# C++ get number of char* in char**

Tags: c++, arrays, string, shell, char

So I have the following function, which splits the char* input by spaces and adds each char* to a char** which is finally returned.

```
char **split_input(char *input) {

  char **command = (char **)malloc(8 * sizeof(char *));
  const char *separator = " ";

  char *parsed;
  int index = 0;

  parsed = strtok(input, separator);
  while (parsed != NULL) {
    command[index] = parsed;
    index++;
    parsed = strtok(NULL, separator);
  }
  command[index] = NULL;

  return command;
}
```

I was wondering if there is any way of getting the amount of char* that the returned char** contains.

Comment: No, unless having a closing sentinel `NULL` value in the array tere's no way to know.

Comment: Is changing your function parameters an option? If so, pass a pointer to a size variable.

Comment: The code shown has *undefined behavior* if the input has 8 or more substrings in it.  The array you allocate can only hold 7 substrings and the terminating NULL sentinel.  Why are you retuning a `char**` in the first place, instead of a `std::vector<std::string>` or at least `std::vector<char*>`? Don't use `strtok()`, there are other ways to tokenize a string in C++ without destroying the input.

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if there is any way of getting the amount of `char*` that the returned `char**` contains.

Given the code you have shown, there is only 1 way - the caller will have to iterate the array counting elements until it reaches the `NULL` at the end.

Otherwise, tweak the function to return the array count alongside the array pointer, either as an optional output parameter, or use a `std::pair<char**, int>` or `struct { char**; int; }` as the return value.